# How to filter collection with more than one value for same field?

Tags: php, magento-1.7

i'm trying to merge two collections which are filtered by same field but with different field value.But the problem is while i'm accessing to resulted merge collection its throwing error like **getMethod can't call on non object magento**.Give me any solution to get it work.
Here is mycode

```
$shippedCollection = array();
$processingCollection = array();
$orderSCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$shippedCollection = $orderSCollection->addFieldToFilter('status','delivered_carrier');
$orderPCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$processingCollection = $orderPCollection->addFieldToFilter('status','processing');
$order = array_merge($shippedCollection->getAllIds(),$processingCollection->getAllIds());


echo $order->getData('increment_id');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                  ->addFieldToFilter('status',array('in'=>array('delivered_carrier','processing')));

echo "<pre>";print_r($orderCollection->getColumnValues('increment_id'));die();
```